# How to identify the type of function generator

Tags: generator

As the model of the function generator TEKTRONIX AFG 3022B didn't mention what type is it? DDS function generator, or analog function generator or digital function generator?  so how to identify it?

Comment: As digital as it gets.

Comment: then it is DDS function generator?as DDS is a type of digital function generator

Comment: No, it is an Arbitrary Function Generator (hence the AFG), i.e. it plays samples from memory.

Comment: @starblue, actually how to differentiate DDS and AFG? as DDS also play sample from memory.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I first check the manufacturer's website, and then Google the model number.  Or the other way around :)

[Here](http://www.tek.com/datasheet/afg3000-series) is the product page at Tektronix. If you can't find the specifics that you are looking for, there is more data on the "specifications" page on the web page.

Good luck!